# Clone userdata from xcover-3 to xcover-3ve g388f -> g389f

Tags: twrp, data-recovery, file-system

I have some very special questions for you.
My friend gave me a broken xcover-3 g388f.
He wants the data on it, so I "Chip off" the internal memory and read it out with a  chip reader. Now he came to me with a newer Xcover-3 model, the g389f and want his data on it. Is there a way to copy the userdata like phonecalls, adressbook and aps from the imagefile of the userdata area on the new model?
I´ve made a backup from the newer phone with twrp an if I compare the two userdata partitions the newer has a smaller size than the older g388f.

Is there a way to mount the backup from the g389f in linux and copy files into it from the chip-off image and write it back to the phone?

Thanks in advice, hope someone can give a good answer.

[image: Image Size of the old/broken phone g388f]
[image: Image Size of the new phone g389f]